# Power BI App Role based row filtering

Tags: ssas, tabular, powerbi, ssas-tabular

I have set up an on-premises Tabular model using Roles to filter data by rows. 
When logging on locally and using Excel this works great and filters as intended. 
Then I use the Power BI Analysis Services Connector as a service bus to access my model in the Power BI App (https://app.powerbi.com). When I log on with the same user account as the Excel scenario my filter does not work and all rows are returned. The user has access to the entire SSAS server, not just the specified models.

I am using Active Directory for user authentication and synch between Azure AD and on-premises AD.

The user I am testing with is not admin.

I have tried to look at the connector settings, but it’s fairly simple and I can’t see what I have done wrong. The connector uses a service account with read and processing user rights.

Why doesn’t Power BI App use the filtering from my tabular model?

Answer (score 0):

1. "The connector uses a service account with read and processing user rights." The Analysis Services Connector service account needs to be an Analysis Services administrator. Otherwise it can't use EffectiveUserName to impersonate the user that's logged into Power BI.
2. Log onto the server as the user you log into app.powerbi.com with. Then pull up a command prompt and run:
   Whoami /upn
   If that doesn't return the exact email address you log into Power BI with that's a problem.
3. What approach do you take to Tabular model security. Do you have a role with a row filter expression and list individual users as role members? Or AD groups as role members? Or do you do dynamic security using the USERNAME() DAX function? Can you post details?
4. Can you check the Power BI user is not an Analysis Services administrator since they get to see all the data?
5. Can you import the Tabular model into SSDT-BI from the server (to ensure the role members are up to date in SSDT-BI) and run this BIDS Helper [feature](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/RolesReport/). It will expand out groups and tell you of any membership issues. Maybe your user is in multiple roles?

Comment: Thank you for answering, and sorry for the late reply. 1. Yes the account is admin. 2. The users computer does not log on to the domain only using the power BI app. 3. USERNAME() dynamic security, but I have tried individual users. Regarding AD it is a local AD sych with Azure AD. MS-SQL 2012 DB

Comment: I ran profiler and the effective user is correct, but the role filter isn't triggered when using the power bi app, only when using Excel.

Comment: Edited my answer with a few more things to check

Comment: The user(s) is not an administrator or part of any admin group. My problem is not with a single user, but all users. Everyone can see all the data when using the Power BI App. Thanks for the tip BIDS Helper looks like a great tool. When running the report I cant find any issues. Thanks again for helping, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe this is just an SSAS bug. Can you make sure you are on the latest SQL Server service pack? Otherwise this might require a support case.

Comment: The Tabular model accepts all connections from the Connector. Impersonation does not work at all. The user does not even need access to the model as long as going through the Power BI SSAS Connector.

Comment: If you watch the connection inside Profiler on one of the early events like Session Initialize (off the top of my head forget which event) you will get a list of roles that user is in. For example, "Sales,Marketing" means the user is in those two roles. But "*,Sales,Marketing" with an asterisk and listing all roles means the user is an admin of the database or SSAS server. Do you see an asterisk in the list when a regular user connects through Power BI? What about when that user connects from Excel?

Comment: Thank you Greg. You are correct, I do get the * asterisk when using the connector. I have checked, double checked and trippel checked that the user is not admin on the domain/server or tabular model/instance. I even tried to create a new AD user and only added it to the domain users group. Still got the same *. When users connects from Excel they are logged in to the domain and not the connector. Then I only get the correct role and not the *.

Comment: Originally when the AS Connector was released, if user1 build the report in the Power BI website and then shared the report with user2, the AS Connector would continue connecting as user1 even when user2 viewed the shared report. However, a few weeks ago, I believe this changed. I'm not clear if this change is retroactive for previously published reports. So who build the report inside the Power BI website? I'm hoping the new AD user you are testing is the creator of the report and that you're not sharing a report that an SSAS admin built previously.

Comment: Can you also describe how you are creating your report in the Power BI website? Are you uploading an Excel workbook which was connected live to SSAS Tabular? Or are doing Get Data and choosing the AS Connector rather than uploading a workbook?

Comment: I have tried all of the above :) Currently using the Get data - then Connector and creating a New report when logged in as the "test-user".